# How to exclude files/directories from find using program argument in bash?

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression

My find looks really simple:

```
find . -type f
```

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude certain files or directories, depending on the program argument line.

```
bash myscript.sh -excl a b c d
```

Where `a, b, c, d` or any next argument of `excl` option is a regex referring to certain files or directories I want to exclude.

So if I called the program this way:

```
bash myscript.sh -excl *.sh somedir
```

I simply want find to ignore somedir directory and all files with `.sh` extension. Is this possible in bash?

Comment: `*.sh` looks more like a globbing pattern with `*` being the wildcard character rather than regex.

Comment: The number of arguments can differ? How should the script distinguish when you are referring to a directory and when to a file name pattern?

Comment: First of all option `-excl a b c d` is not a posix style. Either `--exclude a,b,c,d` or `-e a,b,c,d` or `-e a -e b -e c -e d` or you're confusing most of script's users. Secondly, it's not a bash problem at all. `find` is not a part of `bash`

Comment: The bash part is to quote the arguments to prevent it from being expanded prior to matching. For the rest I would not write a script, but try something like `find /path/to/dir -not -name "*.sh" -not -name somedir` **(untested)**

Answer (score 3):

Solution using `bash` arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a find_arguments=( -type f )

for arg; do

  find_arguments+=( ! -name "$arg" )

done

find . "${find_arguments[@]}"
```

If you really want regex then change `-name` into `-regex` but from your example you seem to want globbing. (BTW, `-regex` is not POSIX but supported by GNU `find`.)

#### Demo

```
touch {a,b,c}{x,y,z}
./myscript.sh 'a*' '*z'
```

Output:

```
./bx
./by
./cx
./cy
```

I left out the command line parsing for `-excl` and such since you didn't make clear how your script's command line options generally look like, if it's truly just `-excl` then you can simply check for it (`[[ "$1" = -excl ]]`) and then `shift`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just add a `-not -name` if there is a second argument to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

targetDir="$1"
exclude="$2"

findString=" '$targetDir'"

if [[ ! -z "$exclude" ]]; then
        findString="$findString -not -name '$exclude'"
fi
eval "find $findString"
```

For example:

```
$ ls
file1  file1.sh  file2  file2.sh  file3.sh  file4.sh  file5.sh
$ foo.sh .
.
./file1
./file2
./file1.sh
./file4.sh
./file3.sh
./file5.sh
./file2.sh
$ foo.sh . '*sh'
.
./file1
./file2
```

If you want to be able to define multiple patterns to exclude:

```
#!/bin/bash 

targetDir="$1"
findString=" '$targetDir'"
shift
exclude="'$1'"
shift
for i in "$@"; do
        exclude="$exclude -a -not -name '$i'";
done
if [[ ! -z "$exclude" ]]; then
        findString="$findString -not -name $exclude"
fi
eval "find $findString"
```

Comment: Putting single quotes around arguments doesn't make them safe to use in `eval`, you also need to handle single quotes inside those arguments.

Comment: Note that `-not` is not standard, the standard equivalent is `!`